# How to return Objects with Object.keys Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, tree

How can i return object with Object.keys in Javascript, React? I would like set my state to something like this:

```
dataset = [
{id:1,text_1:root,father:null,color:"#FF5722"},
{id:2,text_1:child1,father:1,color:"#FFC107"},
{id:3,text_1:child2,father:1,color:"#FFC107"},
{id:4,text_1:child3,father:1,color:"#FFC107"},
{id:5,text_1:child11,father:2,color:"#8BC34A"},
{id:6,text_1:child12,father:2,color:"#8BC34A"},
{id:7,text_1:child13,father:2,color:"#8BC34A"}
]
```

from this Object:

```
{
"root":{
   "child1":{
      "child11":[
         "data"
      ],
      "child12":[
         "data",
         "data",
         "data"
      ],
      "child13":[
         "data"
      ],
      "child14":[
         "data",
      ]
   },
   "child2":{
      "child21":[
         "data"
      ],
      "child22":[
         "data",
         "data",
         "data"
      ],
      "child23":[
         "data"
      ],
      "child24":[
         "data"
      ]
   },
   "child3":{
      "child31":[
         "data"
      ],
      "child32":[
         "data"
      ],
      "child33":[
         "data"
      ],
      "child34":[
         "data",
      ]
   },
   "child4":{
      "child41":[
         "data"
      ],
      "child42":[
         "data",
         "data",
         "data"
      ],
      "child43":[
         "data"
      ],
   },
},
"root1":{
    ...
}
}
```

I tried:

```
setTree([
            {
              id: 1,
              text_1: props.pickedRoot,
              father: null,
              color: "#FF5722",
            },
            Object.keys(res.data.treeData[0][props.pickedRoot]).map(
              (item, i) => ({
                id: i + 2,
                text_1: item,
                father: 1,
                color: "#FFC107",
              })
            ),
          ]);
```

It is almost works except Object.keys returns an array, therefore it gives me an Object and an array of objects. Maybe the problem is that i set my root object separately but i don't really know how could i set it with only one map() function.

Result i get with my solution:

```
0: {id: 1, text_1: "root", father: null, color: "#FF5722"}
1: (7) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

I hope i explained my problem clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `map` function returns an array, that's why you end up with another array inside your array. what i suggest you do is spread the array returned by the `map` with the [spread operator(`...`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```
setTree([
            {
              id: 1,
              text_1: props.pickedRoot,
              father: null,
              color: "#FF5722",
            },
            ...Object.keys(res.data.treeData[0][props.pickedRoot]).map(
              (item, i) => ({
                id: i + 2,
                text_1: item,
                father: 1,
                color: "#FFC107",
              })
            ),
          ]);
```

this way you basically spread all of your new mapped objects into the `tree` array in addition to your first object

#### comment reply

in reply to your comment, you can use [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) if your version supports it, or use an implemented `flatMap` function from a 3rd party library like [`lodash`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#flatMap)

Comment: It's working, i applied your answer, i just have one more question. If i go down one more level with map() function and i want to do something: Object.keys(object).map(item=>...Object.values(object2).map(item2=>item2)), then it return an error. Otherwise if i try to wrap it with ({...Object.values(object2).map(item2=>item2))}) it is working but then again return an rray, how can i get around with this problem?

Comment: the spread operator only works if you are spreading something into an array/object. you cannot just spread an array/object to a return clause (like your first code example in the comment). the `map` function is the one that returns the array, therefore you want to spread it's result. you should put the `...` before the `Object.keys(object).map` to spread the map result

Comment: Yeah, i understand it, i misstyped my example in the comment section. I tried with spread operator: ...Object.keys(object]).map(item=>Object.values(object2).map(item2=>({id:item2,text_1:item2,father:item,color:"#somecolor"}))). No matter i use spread operator in front of the first Object.keys because i have another Object.values inside it and my result will wrapped in an array [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}].

Answer (score 1):

So I just created this function to transform your object into an array:

```
const objToArray = (father, root, globalIndex) => {
const keys = Object.keys(root);

  return keys.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    globalIndex++;
    const id = globalIndex;
    acc.push({
      id,
      text: curr,
      father,
    });
    console.log(globalIndex, acc);
    const children = root[curr];
    if (children.length === undefined) {
      acc.push(...objToArray(id, root[curr], globalIndex));
    }
    globalIndex = acc[acc.length - 1].id;
    return acc;
  }, []);
};
```

This returns n-root elements and can process an object with n levels.